# How to use the same PlotRange and the same PlotLabel size for a sequence of Graphics?

Tags: plotting, animation, labeling

I wish to use `ListAnimate` to show a sequence of plots with different plot ranges and differently sized plot lables, all unknown in advance, in a way that keeps the plots and labels stable in the animation.

For example:

```
frames = 
  Table[
    Plot[x + q, {x, 0, 1}, 
      Frame -> True, 
      PlotLabel -> StringForm["\!\(\*StyleBox[\"q\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) = ``", q]], 
    {q, {1, Sqrt[2], 1/3, Sqrt[3]/2}}]
ListAnimate@frames
```

Basically, I want a way to **post-process** the frames to make them have the widest `PlotRange` and their `PlotLabel` is padded.

```
ListAnimate @ prettifyGraphics @ frames
```

I have some idea on how to guess the effective range of graphics, but no idea on how to measure effective size of their labels and how to pad them. Looking at graphics options doesn't help.

### UPDATE

The list of function plotted is just a sample. In this case, obviously, I know ho to compute the maximum range and I can use across all plots. In a usefuul case assume you cannot know the functions in advance and you cannot easly compute the y-range of values of each function corresponding to x-range of values. You can also assume you completely ignore the way the list of `Graphics` object were generated.

Comment: I think the 'clarification' given in the update makes this question too vague to be answered.

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry for my bad English. Basically I have a list of Graphics objects, constructed in some unknown way, by Plot or even by hand from Graphics primitives like Line and Polygon. I want to **post-process** these graphics objects so that the plot range and plot label size are always the same. If you follow my sample, you should not rely on the knowledge of the function plotted to make the result. The approach of Kuba is what I'm searching for, possibly with a different way to set the height of padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add `Pane` to `PlotLabel` in order to fix it:

```
frames = Table[   Plot[x + q, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
                    PlotLabel -> (Pane[#, {Automatic, 65}] &@   StringForm[
                         "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"q\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) = ``",  q])],
                  {q, {1, Sqrt[2], 1/3, Sqrt[3]/2}}];
```

and here's your function. Keep in mind that `AbsoluteOptions` is not perfect.

```
maxsize = 
 With[{size = MapThread[  
       Compose, 
       {{Min, Max, Min, Max}, 
        Flatten[Transpose[ PlotRange /. (AbsoluteOptions /@ #), {3, 1, 2}], 1]
       }]
      },
   Show[#, PlotRange -> {size[[;; 2]], size[[3 ;;]]}, Axes -> False] & /@ #
   ] &


 ListAnimate[ maxsize @ frames ]
```

Comment: This is basically what I was trying to implement. The only issue is the fixed height (65) of the `Pane`. There is no way to measure the height of each label and use the minimum required height?

Comment: @unlikely well, there is, `Rasterize`+`ImageDimensions` but it is not the cleanest method :/

Comment: While not being exactly a complete and general answer to my question, I choose this as answer (instead of mine) because shown me (with the comment) the right direction to build a more general answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping plot labels with `Pane` as in @kuba's answer and using an alternative method for getting the bounds for plot ranges:

```
ClearAll[resizeAndPaneF, paneF];
paneF[vs_:50] := Pane[PlotLabel /. (Options@#), {Automatic, vs}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}] &;

resizeAndPaneF[vs_:50] :=  With[{pr = PlotRange@Show[#, PlotRange -> All]},
    Show[#, PlotRange -> pr, Axes -> False, PlotLabel -> paneF[vs]@#] & /@ #] &;
```

Using OP's `frames`

```
resizedframes = resizeAndPaneF[]@frames
```

[image]

[image]

An aside: you could also use

```
pr = Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@ Transpose[PlotRange /@ #]
```

to get the bounding plot ranges.

Another: perhaps

```
Row[{Style["q = ", FontSlant -> Italic], q}]
```

instead of ``` StringForm["\!\(\*StyleBox[\"q\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) = ``", q] ```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the defaulted-but-not-fixed height of padding, but AbsoluteOptions is not more robust than Options?

Comment: The use of `Options` with `Graphics` objects appear undocumented, but I now think can be simpler (and more efficient also?) than `AbsoluteOptions`...

Comment: As a C programmer, I like `StringForm` because, like `printf` and similar API, allow a fixed, potentially localized, 'message' to be filled with parameters. On a notebook interface my code doesn't appear so bad :)

Comment: @unlikely, i am using `Options` to get the plot labels only. Regarding `Options` vs `AbsoluteOptions`: `Options[graphicsobj, PlotRange]` will not work for cases where `graphicsobj` has  `PlotRange->All`.

Comment: .. i like `StringForm` too -- and yes, input form does look scary:)

Comment: This use of `PlotRange@Show[#, PlotRange -> All]` is interesting but I think it's not documented :). Among several `Graphics` options is the only one that can be used in this way...

Comment: You are right; it is not documented. I think i first came across it during a spelunking expedition.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Kuba answer and comments I'm now using this implementation:

```
maxPlotRange[glist_] := 
  Through[{Min, Max}[#]] & /@ 
   (* Interval @@@ *) 
    Transpose[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange] & /@ glist];
maxPlotLabelSize[glist_] := 
  Max /@ Transpose@
    Map[Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"] &, 
     PlotLabel /. Options[#, PlotLabel] & /@ glist];
makePrettyFrames[glist_] :=
 With[{maxRange = maxPlotRange[frames], 
   maxLabelSize = maxPlotLabelSize[frames]}, Show[#,
     PlotRange -> maxRange,
     PlotLabel -> 
      Pane[PlotLabel /. Options[#, PlotLabel], 
       ImageSize -> maxLabelSize + {2, 0}, 
       Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
     ] & /@ glist
  ]
```

I initially found interesting the use of `Interval` to combine all plot ranges and to represent with a meaningful symbol the operation done; `Through[{Min, Max}[#]]` get the bounding interval of an `Interval` and handle the case when the `Interval` is composed of several disjoint ranges, i.e. when plot ranges doens't overlap. As of @kguler comment `Interval` proven later to be probably unecessary.

I choose to use `AbsoluteOptions` instead of @kguler way because it's documented and hopefully stable, while not perfect.

As of @Kuba comment, I use `Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"]` to get the size of the plot labels, but apparently it's necessary to add something to the width to prevent the word-wrapping.

Any improvement on this direction appreciated.

Comment: do you have an example where `Interval` makes a difference, that is, where you get a different result when you remove `Interval@@@` ?

Comment: You are right, `Interval@@@` is probably superfluous. I started to use it because represent and remember the operation I'm doing, an union of several ranges. But I later realized that I can end up with an `Interval` still composed of two or more ranges, so I added the `Through[{Min, Max}[#]] &`. At this point `Interval` became unnecessary.