# PlotRange->Automatic the exact function used to calculate outliers

Tags: plotting, options, implementation-details

I know that `PlotRange->Automatic` does the following:

> "the distribution of coordinate values is found, and any points sufficiently far out in the distribution are dropped. Such points are often produced as a result of singularities in functions being plotted."

This quoted verbatim from the the `PlotRange` option page on *Mathematica*.

My question is does anyone know exactly what function Mathematica is using? I have this nifty plotting function I called `ExpPlot[]` that combines a lot of options and plot types. Long story short in *Mathematica* 10.0.2 `PlotRange` is set by only the first set of data in a multiset. I want a simple work around that gives me the "Automatic" plot range option.

Comment: a "not simple" approach is to use `AbsoluteOptions` to discern the auto-range for each plot, then devise a scheme to merge the ranges together.  ( I feel this has been asked before.. )

Comment: relevant.. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61714/how-to-use-the-same-plotrange-and-the-same-plotlabel-size-for-a-sequence-of-grap/61835#61835

Comment: I am not really interested in actually using any kind of option or part of the ListPlot function. I am simply wondering if anyone knows what Mathematica is using for "sufficiently far" out in the distribution. I just want to write something that mirrors the Automatic setting and implement that.

Comment: interesting question, but I think as a practical matter, even if you knew exactly the criteria, in order to to replicate `Plot`'s result you would need to replicate `Plot`'s recursive function mapping to use it.

Comment: I have access to the `PlotRange` option of list plot as well as the input data which is always 2D data sets. So I should be able to replicate it assuming I know what the criteria is, yes?