# How Mathematica chooses PlotRange value?

Tags: plotting, implementation-details

I mean, how Mathematica decides where to clip plot for functions Tan[x], 1/x and likes? Are there some conditions on derivative behaviour, or just absolute value of y-coordinate? I compared this with gnuplot and see, that plotrange in gnuplot in some cases is about 10 times as large as in Mathematica.

Comment: I believe this is the same question as "[PlotRange->Automatic the exact function used to calculate outliers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71808/484)", which unfortunately does not have an answer either.

Comment: This is not documented and I wouldn't even expect it to stay the same between versions.  It just tries to be generally convenient.  But you can always set the plot range yourself.